# Managing data in Stata

Tags: stata

Using Stata 12, I am trying to drop panels from my data set if a certain variable does not change overtime.

For example, in the following data, I want to drop panel `id` 2 and 3 since `Accstnd` does not change over time.

```
id  Accstnd Year
1   DS  1990
1   DS  1991
1   DS  1992
1   DS  1993
1   DS  1994
1   DS  1995
1   DU  1996
1   DU  1997
1   DU  1998
1   DU  1999
1   DU  2000
1   DU  2001
1   DU  2002
1   DU  2003
2   DS  1990
2   DS  1991
2   DS  1992
2   DS  1993
2   DS  1994
2   DS  1995
2   DS  1996
2   DS  1997
2   DS  1998
2   DS  1999
2   DS  2000
2   DS  2001
2   DS  2002
2   DS  2003
2   DS  2004
2   DS  2005
2   DS  2006
2   DS  2007
2   DS  2008
2   DS  2009
2   DS  2010
3   DI  1990
3   DI  1991
3   DI  1992
3   DI  1993
3   DI  1994
3   DI  1995
3   DI  1996
3   DI  1997
3   DI  1998
3   DI  1999
3   DI  2000
3   DI  2001
3   DI  2002
3   DI  2003
3   DI  2004
3   DI  2005
3   DI  2006
3   DI  2007
3   DI  2008
```

It seems like an easy thing to do, but I spent the last few hours trying to figure it out with no luck.

Sorry, I could not attach a picture since I am new to stackoverflow. But if you place this data in an excel sheet, you should see it clearly.

Comment: Because you have spent hours trying, you should post at least one failed attempt (e.g. code) reflecting such an effort. Evidence of research effort is usually expected from users posting questions. A more informative title would also benefit people searching for help in the future.

Comment: The advice to use Excel to view data is bizarre. Many experienced Stata users do not use it at all. If you frame your data with a valid `input` command and `end` you give people who might answer an easy way to experiment with your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
bys id: egen nvals=nvals(accstnd)
drop if nvals==1
```

For each id, you calculate the number of distinct values of accstnd. The you drop the ones where there is no variation.

You will need to install the `egenmore` package.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using first principles and a bit of logic:

```
bysort id (Accstnd): drop if Accstnd[1] == Accstnd[_N]
```

If you sort by `id` and `Accsstnd`, and the first and last observation per panel are equal, then that means the variable holds a constant.

If you have missings in `Accstnd`, further work is needed.

Comment: See also the FAQ http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/